# Data grid view linking

Tags: vb.net

How can I link between two data grid view with button column style for more info: the first button values from data source, and second one button value based on data grid view 1 button text  from database

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking for. Please try to provide a clearer explanation and perhaps an example.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about displaying related data but I'm not sure what the two button columns are for. I could understand one button column in the parent grid to show related child data in a second grid for that record but I don't know what a second button column would be for. Usually, you can [display related data like this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065-Master-Detail-(Parent-Child)-Data-binding-(-NET-2-0-WinForms)) without need for any buttons. If you wanted to use a button then you could bind directly to the child `BindingSource` and set its `Filter` property.